# Typescript: importing internal namespace

Tags: typescript

I'm using a JS module, with typings from `Definitely Typed`, that has this structure:

```
declare namespace Foo {
  interface Bar {}
}

declare module "abc" {
    function f(): Foo.Bar

    namespace f {
    }

    export = f;
}
```

How can I import the `Bar` interface from `"abc"`?

Comment: Unfortunate you can't.
The typings is not defined correctly to expose that.

Comment: You can't import what's not exported. The intent of that typing probably is to expose `Foo` as global object, along with `"abc"` module, and the only thing you can import from `"abc"` is  `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something isn't explicitly exported, chances are, the author of the typings intends for you to not use the type.

...That being said, there technically is a way to get to it. TypeScript added a `ReturnType` type in 2.9 along with conditional types, which allows you to get the return type of a function. Here, you'd use it like this:

```
import f from 'abc'

type Bar = ReturnType<typeof f>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20f()%3A%20Foo.Bar%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20ReturnType%3Ctypeof%20f%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'i%20am%20bar'%20%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!